# Email - How can I generate an alert for messages in a specific folder remaining unread for 1 hour? Or how can I have it moved to Inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, alert

An executive with my company wants to reduce the amount of Spam he processes himself daily. He therefore asked to have all email sent to him from anyone NOT on his Outlook "Safe Senders List" sent to his Junk email folder. Since this would mean he'd eventually miss some important emails falsely identified as spam, he wants to have an assistant check his Junk email folder regularly and move any non-spam messages into the executive's Inbox. ***He wants a safety net, however.*** If new email messages sit in the Junk folder for an hour or more, he wants to be informed directly - in case the assistant is unavailable. He would be fine either receiving some alert, or having the unread messages automatically moved from Junk to his Inbox.

I have figured-out the permissions part, but there doesn't seem to be any means native to Exchange or Outlook to **create an alert or move the message in a specific folder based on how long it's remained unread.** The AutoArchive feature only allows "Delete" or "Move to Archive" as actions - no alert, no move options. Outlook "Rules" don't include a trigger option based on time.

Does anyone know if there is some means to accomplish this through native Exchange or Outlook?
Can anyone suggest a 3rd-party solution that can alert or move emails based on how long they've gone unread?  Many thanks!

Comment: You will need to study [Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Our coders were hoping for something they wouldn't have to write.
Any chance you or anyone else knows of a 3rd-party provider that has a product that could do this?

Comment: Hum, maybe you need to visit some dedicated forum for developer, here we might know little about that.